# Which file should I remove after installation drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My question is I have installed drupal 7.36. After I have installed drupal 7.36 can you just tell me which file is not important after install drupal 7.36 for security purpose.

Answer (score 2):

each files are required for Drupal. Just change the files and directory permissions.

Manual: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 0):

Drupal directories are protected by .htaccess configuration,  so there is no need to manually remove something, just check that .htaccess files are there and working

by the way Drupal 7.38 are available